# Error with spring session [ Cannot expose session attribute 'user' because of an existing model object of the same name]

Tags: java, spring-mvc, velocity

Hi i am getting following error

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Cannot expose session attribute 'user' because of an existing model object of the same name
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractTemplateView.renderMergedOutputModel(AbstractTemplateView.java:141)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
```

Code

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin")
@SessionAttributes("user")
public class AdminHome {    
    @RequestMapping("home")
    public String homePage(HttpSession session, ModelMap map) {
        map.addAttribute(org.brahmaa.ads.util.impl.UserInfo.getPrincipal(session));
        return "admin/home";
    }
}
```

Comment: when does this happen? Is this the whole class?

Comment: It happens when i access /admin/home page. Yes it is the whole class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, `map.addAttribute(org.brahmaa.ads.util.impl.UserInfo.getPrincipal(session));` extracts the `user` attribute from the session and puts it into model. `@SessionAttriubtes` instructs Spring to do the same automatically. Therefore they conflicts. You should use only one of these approaches, not both simultaneously.

Answer (score 3):

I suddenly got this exception as well. Turns out I had added this Freemarker property:

```
<property name="exposeSessionAttributes" value="true"/>
```

Comment: For me, after removing this line from spring config xml resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I use property this in spring-boot

```
spring.freemarker.allow-session-override=true
```